# How to properly iterate over a JSON file in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a list using angular and my data comes from a json file.I'm unable make it work.

My HTML looks like this

```
     <ion-list>
     <div ng-repeat="item in artists" class="card">
      <ion-item class="item-avatar">
      <img src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/">
      <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{item.reknown}}</p>
      </ion-item>
     </div>
     </ion-list>
```

And my angular code is this

```
.controller('listController',['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
  $scope.artists = data;
});
}])
```

and the json data looks like this

```
{
"artists": [
    {

        "name": "Barot Bellingham",
        "reknown": "Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture"
    },
    {


        "name": "Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
        "reknown": "Artist to Watch in 2012"
    },
    {

        "name": "Hillary Hewitt Goldwynn-Post",
        "reknown": "New York University"
    } 
]
}
```

My ng-repeat is somehow not working. Maybe i'm unable to iterate properly over the array of objects. Can you help me out ?

Comment: make sure that `$scope.artists` is an array of objects. probably you should do `$scope.artists = data.artists`

Answer (score 3):

You should access the artists array from the json, It will be like this,

```
app.controller("listController", ["$scope","$http",
    function($scope,$http) {
       $http.get('test.json').then(function (response){
                $scope.artists = response.data.artists;
                console.log(data)
        });

}]);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/l8M1eb8x1E8GTwrdsKuq?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mJP9Je9YpggHruK7aScV) for your problem

Your controller must be

```
app.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data.artists;
  });
```

Your HTML must be

```
<div ng-repeat="item in artists" class="card">
      <ion-item class="item-avatar">
      <img src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/">
      <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{item.reknown}}</p>
      </ion-item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.artists = data['artists'];
        console.log($scope.artists);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey just Try to get the json in php and assigned to the variable you want

```
<?php $json = file_get_contents('your path od json file'.'.json');
      $result =json_decode($json,true);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var inputjson = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
</script>
```